# What is meant by 'Adversarial Perturbation' in Neural Structured Learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nsl

Neural Structured Learning (NSL) has recently been introduced in tensorflow 2.0. I have gone through [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/framework) on NSL on tensorflow site as also [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/adversarial_keras_cnn_mnist) on '*Adversarial regularization for image classification*'. Conceptually, it is not clear to me how this works. How are additional adversarial samples generated, what is meant by adversarial training, and how does it help in achieving greater accuracy/performance? The additional code is really short but what this code is doing behind the scenes is not clear. Will be grateful for a step-by-step inside explanation from a layman's point of view.

Comment: The link you provided explains it pretty clearly and simply: The adversarial examples are constructed to intentionally mislead the model into making wrong predictions or classifications. By training with such examples, the model learns to be robust against adversarial perturbation when making predictions

Comment: My question is how are these images constructed. For example, we already have an Image data generator class in tensorflow 1 to generate variety of images given the original. So how are these adversarial images different? And what next?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case every time, but the explanation given here is that there are the same images they are just labeled incorrectly on purpose. The goal here is to have a model that doesn't break when it encounters bad data because it already trained with bad data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically adversarial examples are created by getting the gradient of the output w.r.t. the input and then maximizing the loss. E.g. if you have a classification task for cats and dogs and you want to create adversarial examples, you input a 256 x 256 cat image into your network, get the gradient of the loss w.r.t. the input, which will be also be a 256 x 256 tensor, then add the negative gradient (perturbation) to your image until the network classifies it as a dog. By training on these generated images again with the correct label, the network becomes more robust to noise/perturbation.

There are also other more sophisticated approaches. For example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10053) explains how a pattern in the input can corrupt the output of an optical flow estimation network.

Comment: May I then put it this way: While image data generator in tensorflow 1 was one way of distorting images and making training more robust, this method is another way of distorting the images (that is generating dog like images for cat while image label remains as cat) and making training robust.

Comment: The intent of introducing deliberate adversarial perturbations so as to train harder becomes clearer if we are also familiar with adversarial attacks. Here is a [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/breaking-neural-networks-with-adversarial-attacks-f4290a9a45aa) to understand them. And here is another [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02697.pdf).

Comment: And here is a good paper on [Adversarial Attacks and Defences: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.00069.pdf).